# Can JAX-WS be used to let a server execute web service calls on a client?

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, jax-ws, p2p

I'm playing around with **P2P**.
I want to use **JAX-WS** for communication inside a P2P network.
Some peers are "behind a firewall", so they **can't listen on ports**.
(They act as clients).
Other peers are allowed to listen on ports. (They act as servers
(and clients)).

Now I want to be able to abstract from the fact, which peers
are server and which not. So, peers have to be able to execute
web-service commands on each other,
with **equal "abilities"** for server peers and client peers.

In a "world without web-services" I would open a socket, and after
the socket is opened, servers could talk to clients
in the same way clients talk to servers
(**in both directions equally**, because the connection stays open).

But JAX-WS is based on (stateless) **HTTP**, and there is no such thing as
"HTTP connections".
**So, servers couldn't make a client call, right?**

What can be done to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you take a look at [JXTA](https://jxta.dev.java.net/) ? This is a Java technology for building peer-to-peer systems, and will handle peers behind firewalls etc.

Obviously you may *have* to use JAX-WS, but you should have a look at JXTA if you're not aware of it. I suspect it'll solve a number of problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

in web service paradigm, you have a 'DIRECTION' for call, there is a client (request initiator) and service (request servant) ... so, if you make both entities (station1 and station2) be in the same time ws-client and ws-server, you can solve this issue.

Another option for clients behind firewall is to POLL the ws-server (client calls periodically the ws to find out news)

Comment: In my question I have written, that some peers are clients-only because they're firewalled. So both client and server will not work for all peers;  I was also thinking about periodic calls, but that would question the necessity for JAX-WS at all.

Comment: polling is just a way to use WS. 
- WS comes with benefits (simplified communication)